# Rails assets manifest file not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to do an initial deploy on to a server and it keeps failing. 
[image]

I'm not entirely sure what the manifest file is. My public folder only has the error pages.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: According to rails convention the default manifest files are application.js and application.css. Can you provide the capistrano script you're trying to run? Or the source from where you're following.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple if you get these types of the issue just do the following

create two empty files in /shared/public/assets called .manifest.json and .sprockets-manifest.json, it will work I am sure.

Cheers